# Spring: injecting bean with path to a file placed in resources folder

Tags: spring

I have following spring bean defined, with one of its property having a file path:

```
<bean class="com.test.MyBean" name="myBean">
    <property name="artifact" value="path/to/MyFile.txt"></property>
</bean>
```

This works fine. But I want to put the file in resources folder. So I modified above as:

```
<property name="artifact" value="classpath:MyFile.txt"></property>
```

But this doesn't work, throwing error that file is not found.

What is the correct way to inject path to a file place in resources folder?

Comment: What is the content of the file ? If they are static content, more of a configuration, like country list or error codes etc.. They you can add them in the configuration and inject the configuration in the bean.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to load a file which is in resource folder and you want to read it.

This manual way you can use:

```
public Resource loadFile() {
    return new ClassPathResource("MyFile.txt"); // Either you can use the value which set on bean value
}
```

Or

```
@Autowired private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public Resource loadFile() {
    return resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:MyFile.txt"); // Here the value would come from xml which you set in bean definition.
}
```

Or

```
public File loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    return ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:MyFile.txt");// Here the value would come from xml which you set in bean definition.
}
```

You can either or way to read the file from classpath.